# How i remove all series from chart(Highcharts) without loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular5

I'm using angular highcharts in my project. I created an area chart with multiple data series,
and I'm trying to redraw the chart with new data series.

I first remove all series one by one with a for loop and then add the new series within another for loop, as seen below.

```
let series = Object.assign([], this.chart.ref.series);
for (var i = series.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    this.chart.removeSeries(i);
}

data.series.forEach((sr) => {
    this.chart.addSeries(sr, true, true);
});
```

When I have 7 or 8 series and redraw the chart, my browser hangs because of the loop.

Is there any way to delete the series without a loop?

TIA.

Comment: what is the problem with deleting them one by one?

Comment: How does your removeSerie(i) function look? If you use [`Highchart.series.remove`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#remove), you can call it with, and without animation, and redraw. If you have both redraw and animation enabled, that will make things slow down.

Comment: hi, I was also thinking of using an {} to store your series instead of using it an array. That way look ups are immediate and so are assignments.

Comment: @82Tuskers i use Object.assign with [] just for copy the series data.

Comment: @ewolden actully i am using a angular plugin name [angular highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts) and that method remove 1 by 1 series from chart reference series.

Comment: I did not explain that well. I was saying if you had a series id (/label) you could use that to index into an object which holds the series. So, look ups and removals can be O(1) without requiring a for-loop. wdyt ?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh So every time you use the `removeSeries(i)` function, the chart redraws itself. you should be doing something like `this.chart.removeSeries(i, false);` within the loop and then doing `this.chart.redraw()` outside of the loop. That way you only draw the entire chart when you want to, not when you are in the middle of editing. same thing goes for the `addSeries()` function

Comment: If the component don't have it, the only way is to delete the chart and create it again, our use another component. But I don't see why you need to delete all without a loop yet

Comment: @rhavelka thank for suggestion. let me try with this.

Comment: Did you consider using [`chart.update(options, redraw, oneToOne, animation)`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update) with `oneToOne` options set to true? Chart will add/remove/update corresponding series for you. Using `series.id` makes this solution even better as docs says.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh, did that solve your problem? if so I can write a formal answer to the question.